# how to remove anchor or add them in blank ul li using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, logic

I want to add an anchor in li and want to remove from another li but don't know how it can be done. Does anyone know how this is possible using jQuery?

add them in blank

```
<li>
<!-- i think to add the anchor here by many attribute --->
</li>

<li>
<!-- this anchor how i can remove -- >
<a></a>
</li>
```

the logic i want to do something like

when event fire :-

```
var cur = cur; // current is variable where i store li who i want to do.
```

how i can remove them from it and how i can add if they really have not anchor on them.

Comment: when what event fires?? and also can you provide some html and then explain the problem analogous to your html

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks -any reason you reworded the question straight after I did? Strange people...

Comment: @Neurofluxation, I had no idea you edited also! I am sorry, was yours better? I saw that there was some HTML not displayed and tried to make the question intelligible.

Comment: @Kyle - no worries, good ol' ping issues eh? You are right though - the code was messy :) I just reworded the English

Comment: I like the code from @kyle and the english from @neuro... What a dilemma. ;-)

Comment: haha, yay - together we are one.

Comment: :D [insert Borg related pun here]

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit unclear exactly what the requirement is, so some handy tips and a couple of examples to get you going:

1) To get a jQuery object for an element, use [`$` (aka `jQuery`)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) and a CSS3 selector:

```
var $element = $("CSS3_selector_for_element");
```

2) To remove an element, use [`remove`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/):

```
$element.remove();
```

3) To *detach* an element (so you can put it back later without losing its event handlers, etc), use [`detach`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/):

```
$element.detach();
```

4) To add or move an element, use [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/), [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/), [`before`](http://api.jquery.com/before/), [`insertBefore`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/), [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/), [`insertAfter`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/), or probably a few others (if you're moving it from somewhere else, no need to `detach` it first):

```
$element.appendTo(target);
```

or

```
jquery_object_for_target.append($element);
```

Very basic example of moving `li`s containing anchors from one list to another when the anchor is clicked:

HTML:

```
<ul id='first'>
  <li><a href='#'>Anchor One</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Anchor Two</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Anchor Three</a></li>
</ul>
<hr>
<ul id='second'>
  <li><a href='#'>Anchor Four</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Anchor Five</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Anchor Six</a></li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript using jQuery:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  $("a").click(function() {
    var $this, li, list, target;

    $this = $(this);
    li = $this.closest('li');
    list = li.closest('ul');
    target = list[0].id == 'first' ? '#second' : '#first';
    $(target).append(li);

    return false;
  });

});​
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/onuwi5)

If you prefer not to figure out where the `li` is when the event first, you can use `delegate` to watch the anchors inside a specific list (the HTML is the same as the above):

```
jQuery(function($) {

  $("#first").delegate('a', 'click', function() {
    return moveContainingListItemTo(this, '#second');
  });
  $("#second").delegate('a', 'click', function() {
    return moveContainingListItemTo(this, '#first');
  });

  function moveContainingListItemTo(element, target) {

    $(element).closest('li').appendTo(target);

    return false;
  }

});​
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/onuwi5/3)

Answer (score 0):

give some class name to that li and the do something like this...

```
$('li ').live('click', function () {

 if(!jQuery("li').hasClass('selected')){

            jQuery(this).addClass('selected').append('<a id="anchor">blah...</a>')
    }else{
             jQuery(this).removeClass('selected').find('a').remove();
}
});
```